# How to weight minimum distance of discrete uniform variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

The question is about the following:

Let there be $n$ discrete uniform variables $(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \in_R [1,L]$ (for large $L$), each variable has a certain weight $(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$ with $Y_i \ge 1$ for all $1 \le i \le n$.

There is one target discrete variable $t \in_R [1,L]$. I would like to know how to use the weights $Y_i$, i.e. a function $f_n(y)$, such that the probability that the weighted distance between $X_j$ and $t$ is the minimum, equals about $\frac{Y_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}$.

So, in short, how to choose function $f_n(y)$ such that:

$Pr[\arg \min_i \{f_n(Y_i)\cdot |X_i - t|\} = j\ |\ Y_1, \ldots, Y_n] = \frac{Y_j}{\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i}$

A function $f_n(y)$ that is approximately correct is also helpful. I did some experiments, and already concluded that $f_n(y)$ should depend on $n$ as well and not only on $y$. I think this has something to with the fact that the minimum of $n$ (discrete) uniform random variables is also dependent on $n$.

Thanks in advance!